# Libgdx: How to replace texture with shaperenderer?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, rendering, ios

I have a method that creates rectangles, it takes a texture

```
 for (Rectangle rect : rect) {
            game.batch.draw(rectImage, rect.x, rect.y);
        }
```

The texture is simple, I could just draw it instead. I created for example

```
shapeRenderer.set(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
shapeRenderer.rect(
        rect.x,
        rect.y,
        rect.width,
        rect.height,
        Color.DARK_GRAY,
);
```

Now what? `game.batch.draw` doesn't accept `shapeRenderer` instead of `rectImage` and doesn't accept only `rect.x, rect.y`

I'm just wondering how to call it?

Comment: By the way, you can't draw Rect through sprite batch, to draw with ShapeRenderer, you need to do it after spriteBatch.end() or before spriteBatch.begin() (depends of what need to be draw on top).

Then :
`shapeRenderer.begin();
 shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    shapeRenderer.rect(rect);
    shapeRenderer.end();
`

Sorry i don't know how to pull code correctly into comment :/

Comment: @SebastienServouze I want to draw it before, I want to draw inside the method which I use to create the rectangles, but then, how to pass the shape to batch.draw()? If I dont have to pass it then what to do? it takes 3 arguments

Comment: You draw in a loop, you can't create your rectangles in this loop ! So you have to declare it in your game class juste once and then use this declaration in your render loop to draw, why do you want to draw them at the same place where your make them ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To draw Shapes over sprites and textures:

1. Make a *shape renderer*

   ```
   ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
   ```
2. *Define* your shape(s)

   ```
   Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
   ```
3. *Open* your batch and *draw* all the stuff which needs to be UNDER your shape. Then *close* your batch.

   ```
   batch.begin();
   // Draw your stuff
   batch.end()
   ```
4. *Draw* your shape(s)

   ```
   shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
   shapeRenderer.setColor(yourColor);
   shapeRenderer.rect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
   shapeRenderer.end();
   ```

If you want gradients and stuff for your shape, `ShapeRenderer.rect()` also has a method where you can put to four colors in (one by top of rectangle).

If you want border for your shape (which can also be gradients) it's also possible with ShapeRenderer

So if you want a specific shape with gradient and stuff, i'll recommend you to build a class which is very similar to sprite, but where the draw method look like the .4 above.

Answer (score 2):

Why you are using shapeRenderer if you want to draw rect type object having different color.

Draw Rectangle using Pixmap. create Texture with given method and use

```
Texture texture=getPixmapTexture(Color.WHITE);

    Sprite sprite=new Sprite(texture); //Used for drawing 2D sprites.
    or
    Image image=new Image(texture);  //2D scene graph node.

    public static Texture getPixmapTexture(Color color){
       return new Texture(PixmapBuilder.getPixmapRectangle(1, 1, color));
    }     

   public static Pixmap getPixmapRectangle(int width, int height, Color color){
       Pixmap pixmap=new Pixmap(width, height, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);
       pixmap.setColor(color);
       pixmap.fillRectangle(0,0, pixmap.getWidth(), pixmap.getHeight());
       return pixmap;
   }
```

Comment: Can I add border and gradient to it?

Comment: you need to use shader for border and gradient

Comment: Ok so it turns out I don't need a pixmap, nor a shaperenderer, i need a shader since I want a rectangle with borders and gradient right? the question now is if I use shader, would I have the same problem I'm facing with shaperenderer? if yes then how to solve it

Comment: @Lynob Consider using a `NinePatch` if you want to draw rectangles with borders.

Comment: @bornander can you elaborate how i can achieve by using NinePatch. Need some useful codes.

Comment: In my understanding, you have to use an image in order to use that, right? If that's so, then I'll just load some textures

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889316/drawing-a-gradient-in-libgdx

Comment: http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=9361

Comment: the first question, they say to use shaperenderer which is what I'm asking about. the second link looks messy, i can't draw all these vertices. I spawn many objects, correct me if I'm wrong but I'd assume it would be much easier to lead texture which is what I'll eventually be doing if it's that complicated.

Comment: easiest way for gradient is use shapeRenderer but i not recommend you because i don't like to work with shapeRenderer. so check second link. In second link you can create gradient without using shader. At the end with use of shader you can do anything but it's tough for beginner you need to know shader language and some knowledge of OpenGL